# Div turns blue if clicked to much

Tags: html

I have a simple div that if clicked to much turns blue: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTKRS/1/)

In Chrome its worse, the whole div(30x30px + some other surounding elements) turns blue. Is there anything I can do about this (other than using img)?

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. As of my understanding, it turns blue when the icon is selected or double clicked. Right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry for asking, but isn't this just you marking it by double-clicking it? The "blue" highlight effect would be the normal behaviour in all browsers...

If you do not want this behavior, you should make sure it is not selectable by applying styles:

```css
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

**Updated:**

For Internet Explorer, use the unselectable tag on your div:

```
<div class="right" unselectable="on">&raquo;</div>
```

Comment: But! But! It doesn't work in Internet Explorer! So your code is broken. Plz halp!

Comment: Add unselectable="on" to the div

Comment: You can also add `::-moz-selection {color: inherit; background-color: inherit;} ::selection {color: inherit; background-color:inherit; }` to allow the selection to be made, but without changing the colours.

Answer (score 2):

This CSS will do the trick:

```
div::selection {
  display:none;
 }​
```

It sets the selection (highlight) to `display:none`, so you don't see it.